# insert multiple data

Tags: php, mysql, insert

how i do wrong i want insert to db data from array:

```
$tabb = array(
  'name' => 'test',
  'login' => 'testt');
```

but i cant use SET, because end of query is char , .

```
public function insert($table, $values){

if($this->database){
print_r($values);
$we = 'INSERT INTO '. $table .' SET ';
foreach($values as $value => $key) {
$we .= ' ('. $value .' = "'. $key .'") ';   
}
print $we;
mysql_query($we);

}
return true;
}
```

i do print $we:

```
INSERT INTO user SET (name = "test") (login = "testt")
```

not work, please help
php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function insert($table, $values)
{
    if($this->database)
    {
        print_r($values);
        $we = 'INSERT INTO '. $table .' SET ';
        $sep = '';
        foreach($values as $value => $key)
        {
            $we .= $sep . ' ('. $value .' = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($key) .'") ';
            $sep = ',';
        }
        print $we;
        mysql_query($we);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or, if you want to be tricky:

```
public function insert($table, $values)
{
    if($this->database)
    {
        print_r($values);
        $we = "insert into `".$table. "` (`". implode('`,`',array_keys($fields))."`) values ('".implode("','",array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $fields))."');";
        print $we;
        mysql_query($we);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I really recommend avoiding `SET`. It is far less common and given the choice between something which is uncommon and something which is common, always go with the common -- it means broader, faster, and better support by your community.

Here's how you'd approach that problem without it:

If you only have two columns in your `USER` table, you can simply use `VALUES` followed by a comma delineated list of data sets:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES ("test","testt"),("test2","testt2")
```

Your function doesn't look like it is geared towards this, but it is a good thing to know either way.

But it looks like you are inserting by column name (a good idea in general):

```
INSERT INTO user (name, login) VALUES ("test","testt")
```

With PHP this becomes:

```
$items = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $values);
$items = '(\'' . implode( '\',\'', $items ) . '\')';
$q = 'INSERT INTO '. 
         $table . 
     // using implode with array_keys assumes that you know all of the keys
     // ahead of time. If you don't, I MUST suggest your re-think your code
     // omit the following line if you want to follow the first SQL example
     ' (' . implode( ',', array_keys( $values ) . ') '.
     ' VALUES ' .
     $items;
```

Comment: MySQL also allows the SET syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function insert($table, $values){
    $fields = array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
        $fields[] = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        $data[] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    }
    $fields = implode(',', $fields);
    $data = implode(',', $data)

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($data);"
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate `(name = "test") (login = "testt")` with ", " between them `(name = "test"), (login = "testt")`

Another way is to do it is:
`INSERT INTO user (name, login) VALUES ("test", "testt")`

Comment: how i can geet name and login from foreach ?